# write out <div> and </div> every fourth row

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

im trying to write out divs every fourth row but im in some kinda zombie mode today that i cant figure it out. it looks like this

```
<% var count = 0; var totalCount = 0; foreach (var item in Model)
   {
       count++; totalCount = Model.Count(); %>
<% if (count % 5 == 0 || count == 1) {%>
   <div class="row-me">
<%} %>

    <div>
        <h2>
            <%= item.Name %>
        </h2>
    </div>

    <% if (count % 4 == 0 || count == totalCount)
       {%>
         </div>
    <%} %>
<%  } %>
```

i want it to be

```
<div class="row-me">
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The condition you want is this:

```
if ((count - 1) % 4 == 0)
```

Examples:

```
(1 - 1) % 4 = 0
(2 - 1) % 4 = 1
(3 - 1) % 4 = 2
(4 - 1) % 4 = 3
(5 - 1) % 4 = 0
(6 - 1) % 4 = 1
(7 - 1) % 4 = 2
(8 - 1) % 4 = 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Not an ASP programmer, but the fact that you're incrementing `count` at the top of the loop could be throwing your calculations off, especially since you're using modulo. `count` is never zero in your loop. Try incrementing count at the last line in your loop and your modulos should make more sense.

Untested:

```
<% var count = 0; var totalCount = 0; foreach (var item in Model)
   {
       totalCount = Model.Count(); %>
<% if (count % 4 == 0) {%>
   <div class="row-me">
<%} %>

    <div>
        <h2>
            <%= item.Name %>
        </h2>
    </div>

    <% if (count % 4 == 0 || count == totalCount)
       {%>
         </div>
    <%} %>
<%  count++;
} %>
```

This should look like:

```
    <div class="row-me"><div><h2>...</h2></div></div>   <!-- count = 0 --> 
    <div><h2>...</h2></div>                             <!-- count = 1 --> 
    <div><h2>...</h2></div>                             <!-- count = 2 --> 
    <div><h2>...</h2></div>                             <!-- count = 3 --> 
    <div class="row-me"><div><h2>...</h2></div></div>   <!-- count = 4 --> 
    <div><h2>...</h2></div>                             <!-- count = 5 --> 
    <div><h2>...</h2></div>                             <!-- count = 6 --> 
    <div><h2>...</h2></div>                             <!-- count = 7 --> 
    <div class="row-me"><div><h2>...</h2></div></div>   <!-- count = 8 -->
```

Where `...` is the output of `item.Name`